# Byte array is a valid UTF8 encoded String in Java but not in Python

Tags: java, python, utf-8, character-encoding

When I run the following in Python 2.7.6, I get an exception:

```
import base64
some_bytes = b"\x80\x02\x03"
print ("base 64 of the bytes:")
print (base64.b64encode(some_bytes))
try:
    print (some_bytes.decode("utf-8"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The output:

```
base 64 of the bytes:
gAID
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

So in Python 2.7.6 the bytes represented as `gAID` are not a valid UTF8.

When I try it in Java 8 (HotSpot 1.8.0_74), using this code:

```
java.util.Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] bytes = decoder.decode("gAID");
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
String s = new String(bytes, charset);
```

I don't get any exception.

How so? Why is the same byte array is valid in Java and invalid in Python, using UTF8 decoding?

Comment: utf8 are the chars from value 0 to decimal 127. 0x80 is decimal 128. So it is definitively not utf8.

Comment: @Humbalan UTF8 uses 0x80+ to encode multi-byte characters. Otherwise it couldn't support non ASCII characters.

Comment: @Humbalan That is incorrect. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) consists of values 0 to 127, but [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is not ASCII and the fact that there is a byte `0x80` does not by itself mean that it is not valid UTF-8.

Comment: `0x80` cannot start a UTF-8 string, since a valid first byte in a UTF-8 char sequence is either `0xxxxxxx` (max. `0x7F`) or `110xxxxx` (at least `0xC0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the String constructor in Java just doesn't throw exceptions in the case of invalid characters. See documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

> public String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
>
> ... This method **always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences** with this charset's default replacement string. The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid UTF8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Bytes between 0x80 and 0xBF cannot be the first byte of a multi-byte character. They can only be the second byte or later.

Java replaces bytes which cannot be decoded with a `?` rather than throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

> So in Python 2.7.6 the bytes represented as gAID are not a valid UTF8.

This is wrong as you try to decode the `Base64` encoded bytes.

```
import base64
some_bytes = b"\x80\x02\x03"
print ("base 64 of the bytes:")
print (base64.b64encode(some_bytes))
# store the decoded bytes
some_bytes = base64.b64encode(some_bytes)
decoded_bytes = [hex(ord(c)) for c in some_bytes]
print ("decoded bytes: ")
print (decoded_bytes)
try:
    print (some_bytes.decode("utf-8"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

output

```
gAID
['0x67', '0x41', '0x49', '0x44']
gAID
```

In Java you try to create a `String` from the Base64 encoded bytes using the UTF-8 charset. Which results (as already answered) in the default replacement character [�](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character).

Running following snippet

```
java.util.Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] bytes = decoder.decode("gAID");
System.out.println("base 64 of the bytes:");
for (byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.printf("x%02x ", b);
}
System.out.println();
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
String s = new String(bytes, charset);
System.out.println(s);
```

produce following output

```
base 64 of the bytes:
x80 x02 x03 
?
```

There you can see the same bytes you are using in the Python snippet. Which lead in Python to `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte` lead there to an `?` (it stands for the default replacement character on a not-unicode console)

Following snippet used the bytes from `gAID` to construct a `String` with the UTF-8 character set.

```
byte[] bytes = "gAID".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
for (byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.printf("x%02x ", b);
}
System.out.println();
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
String s = new String(bytes, charset);
System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
x67 x41 x49 x44 
gAID
```